# Is it possible to intercept commands to a device in Google IOT?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt, iot, google-cloud-iot

Can someone verify for me what I believe I've discovered about Google IOT?

- iotClient.sendCommandToDevice(...) goes straight to the MQTT broker, and does not seem to involve itself with PubSub. PubSub Subscriptions seem to only work with telemetry *from* the device and subtopics thereof. We would like to have some process (perhaps a firebase function triggered on the topic) see all commands going to all devices, and have not been able to do this.
- Connecting to the MQTT broker directly requires a public/private keypair associated with a single device ID, and one apparently cannot subscribe to messages to other devices (for example, one cannot subscribe to "/devices/+/commands/#" or just "#".

We could certainly create a function that duplicated the data, sending it to the device and to a PubSub topic, but we'd much rather have something that more reliably connected to all commands going to devices without requiring that they go through our function.

Comment: Whatever you have discovered is absolutely right.

Comment: Could you please explain why creating your own function is not reliable? in my opinion  this the right way to go for your above problem statement.